# is it possible in Hibernate to live check data and change values

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have following Table "articles" with columns **name**, ..., **endDate**, **active**

Now i want a restriction in hibernate/postgres, that if the endDate is smaller than the actual Date, the column active should be false. I'am not sure if hibernate/Postgres can do such an "live Check". Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EntityListeners` where in you can listen to your entity changes and accordingly whenever there is a change on the endDate or actualDate then you can use your logic and accordingly update the active flag.

given here is an example for the same
http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/24/jpa-entitylisteners/